# Exception in thread main:IO Exception

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

can anyone please help me with this problem,even after removing @ before localhost in my program am unable to run it...this time its giving me error as..
"**Exception in Thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: IO Exception: The Network adapter could not establish the connection**"

```
import java.sql.*;

class CreatingTable{
  public static void main(String[] ar) throws Exception {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:xe","priyanka","java");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    int students=stmt.executeUpdate("create table class(name varchar2(20),rollno number(20)");
    con.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove it? It's part of the [connection string syntax](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC)...

Comment: which OS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

[image: RUN in Windows]

open windows services

[image: Services in Windows]

search for **OracleServiceXE** and **oraclexetnslistener** services and start the services

> **and try this example**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
            String userName = "suru";
            String password = "password";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            System.out.println("Connection success!");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE EMP ( ID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR2(50))";
            stmt.execute(sql);
            System.out.println("Table created successfully!");
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Suru, still am getting the same error as

Comment: java.sql.SQLException:Io Exception:The Network Adapter could not establish the connection....even after trying with your program am getting this error

Comment: when am trying to start ORACLEXETNSListener service its automatically getting stopped

Comment: i think there is a problem installing oracle, try to re istall oracle

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like not have a problem.
problem may be comes from your Oracle XE in local side.

The error message means, oracle XE doesn't accept connection.